# Gigabit Internet confusion

Tags: networking, router, internet

Hi guys first time posting on here, so heres my issue. I got bell fibre installed (1000mbps line) but i wasn't reaching my full speed and was confused. The bell modem speed test shows full gigabit speed give or take 60 or so mbps yet my actual speed tests from speedtest.net or bell's speed test I only reach about 200-300 mbps download speeds. After being on the phone forever and trying everything I started a bunch of downloads and was about to head off to bed. But something strange happened... Having Steam, Battle.net, Oculus and some stuff in Chrome all downloading at the same time. I was reaching my full gigabit download speeds. I'm trying to understand why my speedtests dont get this high or why a single download doesnt reach these speeds. Thanks guys

https://i.stack.imgur.com/33THr.jpg

Heres so images to show.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser.  A better title for this question would be "Internet speed test not showing full speed of connection".  This sort of question has probably been asked before, so it's worth your time trying a couple searches before asking.

Answer (score 1):

Any individual transfer is limited by the slowest link between your computer and the other computer.  So, if anything in the way is slower than 1000 Gbps, then that will be the bottleneck the speed has to conform to.  Finding the source of the bottleneck with random providers is difficult when you don't have visibility into the whole path between you and them.  A single provider will not necessarily be a good indicator of the ISP connection's fastest speed.

Sometimes, providers will put limits on individual download speeds, making the provider itself the bottleneck.  Sometimes, providers are genuinely bogged down under the weight of many downloads at once, and have to divide up their transmission ability between all of their clients.

An "Internet Speed Test" is just providing a medium-sized file to download, and their server may be a couple of network connections away from you, so that some other link in the chain is slowing it down.

One way to discover the "real" ability of the ISP connection is to download simultaneously from multiple sources.  Turn on a Netflix stream and Torrent several Linux ISOs, and watch the throughput in Performance Monitor.

Don't forget to only have one PC or device taxing the ISP connection at a time for your test.

Lastly, most ISPs sell "up to x Mbps" speeds.  The speed isn't guaranteed.  If you want guaranteed speed, be prepared to pay ten times as much for a business connection.

Comment: Thanks for the info. In the picture that I linked I was able to reach my full speed. This was from downloading from multiple streams. So this download cap is that from the ISP itself? or the host im trying to download from.

Comment: Each link in the chain CAN be the limit.  Your ISP will have limits at the rate they've sold you, and any other link in the chain between you and a particular server can be a limiter.  Quality of Service (Qos) is the name for ISPs balancing different users of bandwidth so that everyone gets acceptable speed without one person taking all the bandwidth at once.  You're using Bell Fibre, so they probably have a street corner or neighborhood box doing the routing, and performing rate-limiting if necessary.

Comment: The ISP probably has a 10Gbps fiber to the street corner box, and sells "up to 1Gbps" plans to a hundred houses.  This works well most of the day, when not everyone is taxing their connection simultaneously.  At prime-time 5PM - 11 PM , many of those houses will want to watch Netflix or do other data-heavy actions, so the neighborhood's 10Gbps whole connection must be intelligently managed to give everyone an acceptable rate.

Comment: Thanks everyone I think I understand a bit better now. :)

Comment: Just realized all the comments were by you Christopher, so thank you specifically lol